# List the employee details if and only if more than 10 employees are present in department number 50

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES 
(   
    EMPLOYEE_ID NUMERIC(6,0), 
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(20), 
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(25) CONSTRAINT "EMP_LAST_NAME_NN" NOT NULL, 
    EMAIL VARCHAR(25) CONSTRAINT "EMP_EMAIL_NN" NOT NULL, 
    PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR(20), 
    HIRE_DATE DATE CONSTRAINT "EMP_HIRE_DATE_NN" NOT NULL, 
    JOB_ID VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT "EMP_JOB_NN" NOT NULL, 
    SALARY NUMERIC(8,2), 
    COMMISSION_PCT NUMERIC(2,2), 
    MANAGER_ID NUMERIC(6,0), 
    DEPARTMENT_ID NUMERIC(4,0), 
);
```

I am new to SQL and my assignment requires me to List the employee details if and only if more than 10 employees are present in department number 50. Following is what I did so far:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, PHONE_NUMBER, HIRE_DATE
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID IN 
    (SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID
     FROM EMPLOYEES 
     GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID 
     HAVING COUNT(DEPARTMENT_ID) > 10)
```

But I am not sure how to put the condition `DEPARTMENT_ID = 50`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did the hard part and adding the condition is easy. You can add it to the subquery:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, PHONE_NUMBER, HIRE_DATE
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID IN 
    (SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID
     FROM EMPLOYEES 
     WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = 50
     GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID 
     HAVING COUNT(DEPARTMENT_ID) > 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, you can simply add `WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = 50` within the nested query, but I'm not sure if that's what you what you're getting at because, by filtering on both `WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = 50` and `HAVING COUNT(DEPARTMENT_ID) > 10` you're basically saying: "show me all the employees in department 50, but only if there's more than 10 of them, otherwise show me nothing." Is that what you want?